# Selecting a gallery by data-id and putting child images in array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach

I have a couple of .gallery div's in my html document. Each gallery contains a couple of images. If you click on an image from a specific .gallery with a data-id, i want to put all the images it's src attribute from the same gallery in an array using the gallery it's data id.

this is what i've tried:

```js
$('.img').click(function(){
  var galleryValue = $(this).closest('.gallery').attr('data-id');
  // alert(galleryValue);
  $('.gallery').data('id').children().each(function() {
      urls.push($(this).attr('src'));
      alert(urls);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery" data-id="0">
    <img class="img" src="img/desert.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="img/flowers.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="img/night.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="img/sunset.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="img/surf.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: You are correctly using a contextual selector with the usage of `$(this).closest('.gallery')` to get the related gallery element.  So, why didn't you do the same thing for the logic before the each?

Comment: I got it working like this https://pastebin.com/dBaKeRPD , is every done correctly?

Comment: If it works, it works, :)

Comment: only one thing, a div with the highlighted image pops up, if the other images from the page where still on screen and i click on another one while the highlighted div is active, it breaks the array and puts all images from every gallery in it. this is not the case if the div covers the whole page tho

Comment: That sounds like you have a secondary issue.  `$(this).closest('.gallery').children()` will indeed only find the images related to the gallery of the image you clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.data('id')` returns a string, you cannot chain it into jQuery objects. You can either `.filter('[data-id="'+galleryValue+'"]')` for chaining or add the attribute selection to your actually selector like this:

```js
$('.img').click(function(){
  var galleryValue = $(this).closest('.gallery').data('id');
  // alert(galleryValue);
  urls = [];
  $('.gallery[data-id="'+galleryValue+'"]').children().each(function() {
      urls.push($(this).attr('src'));
  });
  alert(urls);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery" data-id="0">
    <img class="img" src="img/desert.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="img/flowers.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="img/night.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="img/sunset.jpg">
    <img class="img" src="img/surf.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('.img').click(function(){
  var urls = [];
  $(this).closest('.gallery').find('img').each(function() {
    urls.push($(this).attr('src'));
  });
  // now do something with urls
});
```

If you also need the `id` then you can grab that as you traverse as well. But for just finding the images in the same container, you can just do it totally contextually.

Comment: I agree that this is leaner (obviously). As long as the source of the data-id and the images are related this would be preferable.